# Change Menu hover to click/active CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I tried to change my menu from hover to click  but if i click the menu the sub-menus also close so fast I think I need a javascript for onclick and toggle but don't know how to be done. Please help I'am a newbie

```css
/* menu */
 #menu{ margin:0px 0px; margin-top:67px; margin-left:90px; list-style:none; color:#fff; line-height:30px; display:inline-block; float:left;  height:-100px; width:1000px; }
            #menu1{ margin:0px 0px; margin-top:auto; margin-left:-50px; list-style:none; color:#fff; line-height:30px; display:inline-block; float:left;  height:auto; width:95px; }
    #menu a { color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
    #menu > li {background:#fff none repeat scroll 0 0; cursor:pointer; float:left; position:relative;padding:0px 10px; z-index:999 !important;}
    #menu > li a:hover {color:#B0D730;}
    #menu .logo {background:transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%; padding:0px; background-color:Transparent;}
    /* sub-menus*/
    #menu ul { padding:0px; margin:0px; display:block; display:inline;}
    #menu li ul { position:absolute; left:-10px; top:0px; margin-top:30px; width:200px; line-height:16px; background-color:#FFF; color:#FFF; /* for IE */                       display:none; }
    #menu li:hover ul { display:block;}
    #menu li ul li{ display:block; margin:5px 20px; padding: 5px 0px;  border-top: dotted 1px #606060; list-style-type:none; }
    #menu li ul li:first-child { border-top: none; }
    #menu li ul li a { display:block; color:#0395CC; }
    #menu li ul li a:hover { color:#7FCDFE; }
    /* main submenu */
    #menu #main { left:0px; top:-20px; padding-top:20px; background-color:#FFF; color:#fff; z-index:999 !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## On Click

In your HTML code, you can have Javascript actions happen on click:

```
<p onclick="clickedText()">Click Me!</p>
```

The necessary Javascript code would be:

```
var clickedText = function() {
    //Insert Code Here That's On Click
}
```

To access an element by id use the following Javascript code:

```
var element = document.getElementById("id");
```

Then you can use:

```
element.style.display = "none";
```

---

## Speed

If something is closing too fast, and you are using `display: none;`, that is because you are telling the browser to display nothing this exact second.

Your CSS code is *telling* the browser to not display the submenu.

---

## CSS Code

This is where a sample of your HTML file would come in handy. You are telling the browser the following:

```
#menu li:hover ul { /*Do stuff*/ }
```

That means it selects all `ul` **in** a hovered upon `li` that is **in** `#menu`.

I think that a [CSS Selector Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) would help you a lot.

---

## Suggestions

- I suggest that you give a snippet of the HTML code.
- I suggest that you try [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp), [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp), and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) tutorial.
- I suggest that you take a look at the `:not()` CSS selector.